# How can I send a zip file from local to remote and save it to remote directory when connecting directly to remote server is not an option?

Tags: kdb

I am trying to send local files of any type over to a remote instance. I thought the best way of handling this is to send the files in zip file and unpack on the remote server using the unzip system command.

I can do this for q files...

```
upload:{[content; name] name set content; temp: `$"/tmp/files/", string[name], ".q"; save temp};

{h(upload; read0 paths[x]; `$names[x])} each til count names
```

where

1. `h` - the `hopen` connection
2. `/tmp/files` is the remote directory
3. `paths` - local file paths as symbol
4. `names` - file names

Any other file gets messed up even text files.

Also, changing `read1` to read in as bytes will cause a type error in the defined method.

Any way to do this?

Note options like scp or rsync are not options as connecting directly to remote server is not an option

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using different families of functions to read and write the files, resulting in incompatible formats. `get/set` (including `load/save`) assume kdb+ serialization format. `read0` and `0:` assume text while `read1` and `1:` assume binary. So if you read with `read0` you should write with `0:`, and if you read with `get` you should write with `set/save`.

Comment: I marked yours as the answer since it clarifies thing but ultimately prefer the handling I've added. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Switched to `pykx` which makes things a bit easier to do between local and remote...

```
# Read in bytes of file via read1 and set full path for remote
pykx.q('someZipFile: read1 `$"/path/to/local/file"; fullPath: `$"/path/for/remote/file")')

# assign the variables which are binaries to the remote instance
pykx_remote['someZipFile'] = pykx.q('someZipFile')
pykx_remote['fullPath'] = pykx.q('fullPath')

# now write to remote
pykx_remote('fullPath 1: someZipfile')
```

https://code.kx.com/q4m3/11_IO/

> If you want to write raw binary data, as opposed to the internal
> representation of a q entity containing the data, use the
> infelicitously named 1:. It takes a symbolic file ha6ndle as its left
> argument and a simple byte list as its right argument. Bytes in the
> right operand are essentially streamed to the file.6